# How can I include ui-bootstrap in a plunker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I created the following plunker:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/c0pGkinMpXBBT1dpLxAo?p=preview
```

But this gives me an error with the line where I try to include a reference to ui-bootstrap

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="//github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
```

I am not very experienced with creating plunkers. Can someone give me some advice as to what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find and add external libraries from the right side bar in most cases (from the little button that looks like a book), but I think your error stems from that you're linking to the GitHub page instead of the actual script.

The correct link should be:
https://raw.github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-0.4.0.js

Comment: Plunker does not add external library references in the way that it claims to. In my case, I was trying to add ng-grid and ui-bootstrap references to an angularjs plunk. Most frustrating.